# Trouble with SQL CASE construct

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to assign a transaction type' to invoices by running them against a set of business rules to make the determination.  The database contains an Invoice Header table (SOP10100), Invoice Lines (SOP10200) and our Items table (IV00101).  Some conditions are satisfied at the Header level (CUST#), others require I test to see if any of the Line Items in a particular invoice contain a certain ItemClassCode (from the Items table).  And in the end, if none of the criteria are met, a 'No Transaction Type' code is used.

In testing, the I have some invoices that meet the first 3 cases, some that meet the 5th ('456') and none that meet the 4th ('123') and some that meet none of the conditions.  The results are fine for all except those that meet none of the criteria.  Those records do not fall through to the ELSE, instead they are given the '456'.

I think I understand what is happening. The queries in the WHEN statements are not being run with the current Invoice header record.... it is being run with all Invoice headers.

Did I make this understandable and can anyone help?

Thanks

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    OH.SOPNUMBE SOPMNBR,
    OH.ORDRDATE ORDERDATE,
    OH.ORIGNUMB ORIGNUM,
    OH.CUSTNMBR CUSTOMER,
    OH.INVODATE,
    CASE    WHEN OH.CUSTNMBR = 'CUST1' THEN 'First'
            WHEN OH.CUSTNMBR = 'CUST2' THEN 'Second'
            WHEN OH.CUSTNMBR = 'CUST3' THEN 'Third'
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT OH.SOPNUMBE,
                                OL.SOPNUMBE,
                                IV.ITEMNMBR,
                                IV.ITMCLSCD
                        FROM SOP10100 OH
                        INNER JOIN SOP10200 OL ON OH.SOPNUMBE = OL.SOPNUMBE
                        INNER JOIN IV00101 IV ON OL.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
                        WHERE LEFT(IV.ITMCLSCD,3)='123'
                        AND OH.SOPTYPE=3
                        AND OH.PSTGSTUS = 0
                        AND OH.VOIDSTTS = 0
                        AND OH.BACHNUMB <>'DO NOT POST') THEN '123'
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT OH.SOPNUMBE,
                                OL.SOPNUMBE,
                                IV.ITEMNMBR,
                                IV.ITMCLSCD
                        FROM SOP10100 OH
                        INNER JOIN SOP10200 OL ON OH.SOPNUMBE = OL.SOPNUMBE
                        INNER JOIN IV00101 IV ON OL.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
                        WHERE IV.ITMCLSCD = '456'
                        AND OH.SOPTYPE=3
                        AND OH.PSTGSTUS = 0
                        AND OH.VOIDSTTS = 0
                        AND OH.BACHNUMB <>'DO NOT POST') THEN '456'
            ELSE 'NO TRANSACTION TYPE' 
    END  TRANSTYPE
FROM SOP10100 OH 
INNER JOIN SOP10200 OL ON OH.SOPNUMBE = OL.SOPNUMBE
INNER JOIN IV00101 IV ON OL.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
WHERE OH.SOPTYPE=3
AND OL.SOPNUMBE = OH.SOPNUMBE 
AND OH.PSTGSTUS = 0
AND OH.VOIDSTTS = 0
AND OH.BACHNUMB <>'DO NOT POST'
```

Comment: Do you not just need to check if they are all NOT NULL? Also, I do not think  AND OL.SOPNUMBE = OH.SOPNUMBE  is required in your WHERE clause as you are using an inner join on that condition.

Comment: Yes, I just want to check for absence or presence so that I can either assign the TransType or move off to the next WHEN.  Apparently my subquery is not restricted to the invoice number in the main query, and because of that the '456' query is always true.